# How to update a many to many relationship that has fields extra to its foreign keys

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

I’m implementing a project using asp.net core. Employing DB first approach and creating models in Visual studio, in SQl server I have two tables called API and Applicant that have many to many relationship and there is also their junction table called ApiApplicant.
Suppose these 3 tables has the following fields each:
Api: ID, name,date
Applicant:Id,name,type
ApiAppliant:Id,ApiID,ApplicantId,reqDate,gateId
My ApiApplicant table also has many to one relationship with another table called Gate.Gate table has the following fields:Id, name,
Now I want to know how can I update ApiApplicant table in my code.
I appreciate if anyone solve the above problem by showing me a sample relevant linq code.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how you would like to update the junction table.You does not show any code.

Anyany, you could firstly remove all original records which you want to update and then add new records.

Below is a demo which updates an existing Api's related Applicants.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(long id, Api api)
{
    if (id != api.ID)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
           //your new ApplicantIds
            var newSelectedApplicantIds = new int[] { 3,4 };
            var apiApplicants = new List<ApiApplicant>();


            var apiAppList = await _context.ApiApplicant.Where(a => a.ApiID == api.Id).ToListAsync() ;
            _context.RemoveRange(apiAppList);

            foreach (var newid in newSelectedApplicantIds)
            {
                var item = new ApiApplicant()
                {
                    ApiID = api.Id,
                    ApplicantId = newid,
                };
                apiApplicants.Add(item);
            }
            _context.AddRange(apiApplicants);
            _context.Update(api);

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {

        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(api);
}
```